# Class 'IlluminateSessionTokenMismatchException' not found

Tags: php, laravel-4

I`m using [laravel cms crud builder](http://codecanyon.net/item/laravel-cms-crud-builder-administrator/7194641?s_phrase=&s_rank=31) in my project. All works fine on localhost, but when I move it to production(shared hosting) and try to login appear error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'IlluminateSessionTokenMismatchException' not found
```

Because of shared hosting I can`t try to solve problem with composer/artisan.

I`ve tried to set session driver to database, file, cookie.

Thanks.